# Mean of skew normal distribution with normal prior obtained with Gibbs sampling

Tags: r, bayesian, normal-distribution, gibbs, skew-normal-distribution

I would like to obtain a new mean $\mu$ of a skew normal distribution with a normal prior of the form $N(\delta,\tau)$ on $\mu$, and a given standard deviation $\sigma$ and shape parameter $\alpha$. For this end, I am trying to implement a Gibbs sampler described in [Kim 2005: Bayesian estimation for skew normal distributions using data augmentation](http://koreascience.or.kr/article/JAKO200504840590864.pdf).

Let $x$ be the mean of the original skew normal distribution:

$x$ ~ $SN(\mu,\sigma,\alpha)$
$\mu$ ~ $N(\delta,\tau)$

The approach by Kim (2005) uses the auxiliary variables $z$ and $y$ to obtain $\mu$, conditional on $\sigma$, $\rho$, $x$ and $y$ with a Gibbs sampler:
$z = (x-\mu)/\sigma$
$y$ ~ $N(\rho z , \sqrt{1-\rho^2)}$       with $\rho = \alpha/\sqrt {1+a^2}$  and
$\mu$ ~ $N(\frac{\tau^2 (x-\sigma \rho y)+\sigma^2 (1-\rho^2) \delta}{\tau^2 + \sigma^2 (1-\rho^2)},
\sqrt{\frac{\tau^2 \sigma^2 (1-\rho^2)}{\tau^2 + \sigma^2 (1-\rho^2)})}$

(I use only a single value of $x$, i.e. the mean, rather than samples from the skew normal distribution, hence I set all the $n$ for the sample size to $1$.)

As an example, let's set
$x = 4$, $\sigma = 2$, $\alpha = -5$
$\delta = 1$, $\tau = 2$

In R code, this looks like this:

```
# Data
x = 4
sigma = 2
alpha = -5
# transform alpha
rho = alpha/sqrt(1+alpha^2)

# Prior parameters
delta = 1
tau = 2

# prepare Gibbs sampling
N = 10000 # number of iterations
mu <- rep(NA,N) # vector to store mu
mu[1] <- 1 # initial value of mu

# Gibbs sampling
for(i in 2:N){
z <- (x - mu[i-1])/sigma 
y <- truncnorm::rtruncnorm(1,0,Inf,rho*z,sqrt(1-rho^2)) # needs truncnorm package
mu[i] <- rnorm(1,(tau^2*(x-sigma*rho*y)+sigma^2*(1-rho^2)*delta)/(tau^2+sigma^2*(1-rho^2)),
               sqrt((tau^2*sigma^2*(1-rho^2))/(tau^2+sigma^2*(1-rho^2))))
}
```

The result of this analysis is not what I would expect. The posterior of $\mu$ seems to be pushed away from the prior ($\bar{\mu} = 4.6$):
[image]

When the sign of $\alpha$ is reversed ($\alpha = 5$), the posterior of $\mu$ has a larger variance and seems to match the prior more than the data ($\bar{\mu} = 2.1$):
[image]

When I set $\alpha = 0$, the posterior of $\mu$ looks as it should be, right between the prior and the data ($\bar{\mu} = 2.5$):

[image]

I'm failing to understand what is going wrong in the cases where $\alpha \neq 0$, and I'd appreciate any help!